# How to play different audio based on which div is in view?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a website that depending on which div is in view will play a different audio file.

The only thing closely related that I could find was different audio playing depending on specific height locations of the website, i.e. between start height = 1000px and end height = 1400px play X music. Example here: http://home.jejaju.com/play/smoothFade/tracks

The only issue with this approach is that my website is responsive, so depending if you're on mobile or desktop will have different heights.

Any ideas or examples on how to approach this?

Comment: you could use the [onfocus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) to switch between audios

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using the [intersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)? You can choose to play the audio based on the ratio of the `div` being within the viewport.